# Will the code in Azure change for the web app bot when published from VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, botframework

I've published the code from Visual studio, but I don't see the code changes that I made for the bot reflecting anywhere in the azure online editor. Will the code get changed or not ?

Comment: When you say in the Azure online editor, do you mean the `Azure App Service Editor`? What are the file types that you are comparing changes for?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the publishing configuration is publishing to the correct location and no errors occurring, then it should publish the changed/added code to the Azure Web App. Also, it depends on what (files) exactly you are looking at. Any code changes should be represented in a date change in the .dll that gets published. Other files, depend on what types they are. You can check the properties in Visual Studio to see if `Copy to Output Directory` to see if it will be added to the output folder and published.